# How to load .png images with image names listed in a .csv file to R

Tags: r, csv, png, imagick

I am using a simple code below to append multiple images together with the R magick package. It works well, however, there are many images to process and their names are stored in a .csv file. Could anyone advise on how to load the image names to the image_read function from specific cells in a .csv file (see example below the code)? So far, I was not able to find anything appropriate that would solve this.

```
library (magick)

pic_A <- image_read('A.png')
pic_B <- image_read('B.png')
pic_C <- image_read('C.png')

combined <- c(pic_A, pic_B, pic_C)
combined <- image_scale(combined, "300x300")
image_info(combined)
final <- image_append(image_scale(combined, "x120"))
print(final)
image_write(final, "final.png") #to save
```

[image]

Comment: Can give a clear answer if you can share a few lines of the csv file (so we can understand the format/contents).
In anycase, the `image_read` function should work fine with variables, so all I think you need is loop (or apply function). 
Something like `pic_A <- image_read(csv_df$A[i])` should work where `i` is the loop index and `csv_df$A` contains the filename for the first png.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. Please see an example of how the .csv file is organised. I need to merge (append) the three images in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. If you load the csv into a dataframe then, it's then straightforward to point the `image_read` towards the appropriate elements.

And the index (row number) is included in the output filename so that things are not overwritten each iteration.

```
library (magick)

file_list <- read.csv("your.csv",header = F)
names(file_list) <- c("A","B","C")

for (i in 1:nrow(file_list)){
pic_A <- image_read(file_list$A[i])
pic_B <- image_read(file_list$B[i])
pic_C <- image_read(file_list$C[i])

combined <- c(pic_A, pic_B, pic_C)
combined <- image_scale(combined, "300x300")
image_info(combined)
final <- image_append(image_scale(combined, "x120"))
print(final)
image_write(final, paste0("final_",i,".png")) #to save
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Managed to confuse myself, but this works really well!